# Left click on Ubuntu 14.10 don't work

Tags: 14.10, vmware, ubuntu-gnome

I have done a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.10 using VMware. But, the left click function works partially.

I can't open files, folders or tick check boxes, which renders me nuts. I can, however, open programs, make selections from menus and such/

I have done many installations in the past and this is the first time I have ever experienced such.

Can anyone offer some assistance on the resolution of the inconvenience?

Comment: Right click has never opened files. It opened menu where opening the file may have been one of the options. Or are you using left-handed mouse?

Comment: I changed the primary button to the right, to aid in my left handedness.

Comment: You may want to edit the question to indicate this fact. Otherwise it's confusing.

Comment: @Volodya I have edit it. Let me point out that whether I leave the primary key as left or I change it to right, the same functionality is received.

Comment: Edit the title too. Anyhow, what's probably happened here is you've edited the button mappings incorrectly. Explain exactly what you've done to change the buttons around, or nobody will be able to help you.